# Angular load file.json and convert to object class

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, angularfire

My app load a file.json of users'pc:

**app.component.html**

```html
  <div class="file btn btn-lg btn-primary">
    Upload
    <input type="file" class="upload" (change)="changeListener($event.target.files)">
  </div>
```

In my **app.component.ts**

```
  user: User;
  userArray: Array<User>;
  fileList: Array<any>;

  ngOnInit() {
   this.user = new User();
   this.userArray= Array<User>();
   this.fileList= Array<any>();
  }
```

THEN the method that receive file:

```
  public changeListener(files: FileList) {
    if (files && files.length > 0) {
      let file: File = files.item(0);

      let reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsText(file);
      reader.onload = (e) => {
        let loadFile: string = reader.result;
        JSON.stringify(loadFile)
        this.fileList = loadFile.split('\r\n');

    if (this.fileList.length > 0) {
      for (const i of this.fileList) {
        if (i !== null) {

          this.user = i; //--I THINK HERE IS MY PROBLEM--
          this.userArray.push(this.user); //----HERE IS UNDEFINED

          console.log('user - ', this.user); 
        } else {
          console.log('NULL');
        }
      }
        console.log('userArray - ', this.userArray.length); //---BUT HERE SHOW SIZE OF .JSON LOADED
      }
    }
  }
```

My question is: **Like to convert 'i' in User object? Or fileList in user Array?**

my user.class have same properties of json.file...I see a lot responses here but nothing works.

My json file is a list of:

```
{"DATE ":"22/04/2018","HOUR ":"03:00:55","YEAR ":2014,"NUM_TURN (*) ":1,"DESC_E (*) ":"Gerais 2014","SIGLA_UF ":"SE","SIGLA_UE (*) ":"SE", ...e more others 15 properties}
```

Comment: you are assigning "i" directly to your User class shouldn't that be like
    this.user.firstName=  i;

Comment: my .json file is a list with lot this: {"DATE ":"22/04/2018","HOUR ":"03:00:55","YEAR ":2014,"NUM_TURN (*) ":1,"DESC_E (*) ":"Gerais 2014","SIGLA_UF ":"SE","SIGLA_UE (*) ":"SE", ...e more others 15 properties}

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you using `fileList` instead of `this.fileList`?

Anyway I would try to cast `i`:

```
this.user = i as User;
```

Comment: sry about fileList  in my real code this area is in other method that pass fileList by parameter but I fix now.  this.user = i as User;
          console.log('name - ', this.user.name); is undefined

Answer (score 0):

`fileList` is an array of strings, so you need to convert `i`, which is a string (although with the type `any` in this case), to a json object:

```
this.user = JSON.parse(i);
```